# I get this error Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s' while resizing image in open cv2

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code:

```
# loading image from folder
folders = glob.glob('path to folder ')

imagenames_list = []

for folder in folders:
    for f in glob.glob(folder+'/*.jpg'):
        imagenames_list.append(f)

read_images = []        

for image in imagenames_list:
    read_images.append(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))

re_size = cv2.resize(read_images, (50,50), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

**I get this error**

```
Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: I find a simple solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983690/13181871

Comment: H find a simple solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983690/13181871

Answer (score 1):

I changed the data type from float16 to float32, solving the problem:

```
images.astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: not working for me..

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because you are feeding a list instead of numpy array of image to cv2.resize.

```
re_size = [cv2.resize(img, (50,50), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR) for img in read_images]
```

should fix that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that as it is a function of OpenCV. So the best way is to read the image using
`cv2` and then utilize the image or convert the image to `numpy.ndarray`.
Hope so it will be helpful

```
path=r'C:\Users\imzia\Rb\S010_004_00000019.png'
image=cv2.imread(path)  
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.Color_BGR2GRAY)
```